# Google maps addListener loads only one marker closure issue

Tags: javascript, google-maps, closures

I am trying to load google maps markers when I move the viewport but only the marker that I added last is loading. I think its a closure issue. This is part of my code:

```
function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(42.271084, -83.737277),
      zoom: 16
    });
   downloadUrl('/data', function(results) {
      var resultsJSON = JSON.parse(results.responseText).data;
      for (var i = 0; i < resultsJSON.length; i++) {
      var lat = resultsJSON[i].lat;
      var lng = resultsJSON[i].lng;
      var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng,
        map: map,
        category:year,
        icon: icon.style,
        scale: 2
      });

      if(map.getBounds().contains(marker.getPosition())) {
        marker.setMap(map);
      }
      else {
        marker.setMap(null);
      }  
      google.maps.event.addListener(map, "idle", function() {loadMarker(map, marker)});
     }
    });
  }
 function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
    #ajax call
  }
  function loadMarker(map, marker) {
        if(map.getBounds().contains(marker.getPosition())) {
        marker.setMap(map);
        console.log("Hello world");
      }
      else {
        marker.setMap(null);
      } 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You use this command inside cycle

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, "idle", function() {loadMarker(map, marker)});
```

In each iteration of the loop, you try add to event 'idle' an anonymous function. And in every transaction you rewrite this function with new function with new data. As result in last transaction the marker that you added last is loading. You should create an array of markers and pass them after the end of the loop. Something like this:

```
   downloadUrl('/data', function(results) {
      var resultsJSON = JSON.parse(results.responseText).data;
      var markers = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < resultsJSON.length; i++) {
      var lat = resultsJSON[i].lat;
      var lng = resultsJSON[i].lng;
      var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng,
        map: map,
        category:year,
        icon: icon.style,
        scale: 2
      });
       markers[i] = marker;
     }
     loadMarker(map, markers);
     google.maps.event.addListener(map, "idle", function() {loadMarker(map, markers)});
    });

 function loadMarker(map, markers) {
       for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        if(map.getBounds().contains(markers[i].getPosition())) {
        markers[i].setMap(map);
        console.log("Hello world");
      }
      else {
        markers[i].setMap(null);
      } 
     }
  }
```

Comment: You get errors in console, or something else?  What result of this code?

Comment: It doesn't work. The code you posted causes all the markers to load at once. I want the markers to load only when they are in the maps viewport.